# fonts not applied to high ASCII characters

Tags: 7, theming

After installing the @fontyourface module and adding some Korean fonts locally, the fonts are not being applied to high ASCII characters (which makes no sense as the font is specifically for those characters). The fonts ARE applying to the regular ASCII characters, though.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bugreport for module, or for specific fonts used. Please file a bugreport in appropriate issue queue.

Comment: No- it's not a bug report or for specific fonts. The issue is that fonts are not applying for high ASCII characters regardless of the font specified (including the default fonts). These were used for illustration as they are specific to high ASCII characters (and to preempt the answers of "try installing @fontyourface or related module"). The question is out there for any users who have experienced the problem, regardless of specific modules or fonts used.

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, the issue was NOT off-topic. It turns out that the downloaded fonts were not set for Unicode. Most likely, they were using the euc-kr character set. Since the site uses utf-8, the ranges for the characters in utf-8 are different from euc-kr, so the default font was being used to display.

I downloaded a different version that specifically listed the font as Unicode and now the characters display correctly for that font.